# Python3: detect keypresses asynchronously and communicate them to the main thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, keyboard, stdin

**Disclaimer**: the import statements are within the functions, I know that this is uncommon. I am showing my whole program here by showing it function for function while telling my issue and my thinking. In reality, I am doing something different, I made this minimal example just for this Stackoverflow question. There are duplicate questions, but I did not find good answers in them since those only say "use multithreading" (e.g. [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/197575/python-reading-from-stdin-while-doing-other-tasks)). This particular question concerns itself with how to use multithreading.

**The Story**: I am running a program in Python. Let's say that it is a while loop going on to infinity. It just runs happily. For example,

```
def job(threadname, q):
  from time import sleep
  c = 0
  while True:
    sleep(0.1) #slow the loop down 
    c += 1
    print(c)
```

What I want to be able to do is that it asynchronously detects a keypress on `stdin` and then interrupts execution, so that I can do whatever I want within the function it is interrupted in (or if I am running it with `python3 -i program.py`, to switch over to the REPL with all my modules loaded in, remember this is a minimal example in which I do not want to highlight such concerns too much).

My idea was: I have one function that asynchronously gets the keypress, sends it via a queue to the other thread and it works. So I extended the job function as such:

```
def job(threadname, q):
  from time import sleep
  c = 0
  while True:
    sleep(0.1) #slow the loop down 
    c += 1
    print(c)
    ch = q.get() #extension for multithreading
    handle_keypress(ch) #extension for handling keypresses
```

The code for `handle_keypress(ch)` is:

```
def handle_keypress(key):
  if (key == "q"):
    print("Quit thread")
    exit(0)
  elif (key == "s"):
    print("would you like to change the step size? This has not been implemented yet.")
  else:
    print("you pressed another key, how nice! Unfortunately, there are not anymore options available yet.")
```

In other words, not that interesting other than to showcase that I want to be able to do this.

At first the issue seemed to be in the `job()` function. The culprit is `q.get()`, which is hanging. However, it is hanging because my input thread for some reason is not asynchronous and blocks. I have no clue how to make it unblocked.

This is the function of my input thread:

```
def get_input(threadname, q):
  #get one character, this code is adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user
  while True:
    import sys, tty, termios
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
    q.put(ch)
```

It is obvious to me that `sys.stdin.read(1)` is blocking, but I don't know how to make it unblocked. In the state that it is now, I also cannot think of a way to handle the poison pill situation, which is why `q.get()` in the `job()` function is blocking.

I run the program by calling the following function:

```
def run_program():
  from threading import Thread
  from queue import Queue
  queue = Queue()
  thread1 = Thread( target=get_input, args=("Thread-1", queue) )
  thread2 = Thread( target=job, args=("Thread-2", queue) )

  thread1.start()
  thread2.start()
  thread1.join()
  thread2.join()
```

**My Questions**: is this how you would design a program to deal with asynchronous keypresses? If so, how do I make the `get_input()` function unblocked?

Comment: `get_input()` must be blocking, it has no other work when no keypresses. `job()` must not block, because it's worker which do some processing. To fix it you must use `queue.get(block=False)` and check if returned `ch` is not None. If it's None just do your work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sav I found a way to answer this question. In my opinion, his comment is the answer. So if he'll rewrite his comment. I'll accept his answer. For now, I will show what part of the code I changed in order to get a non-blocking implementation working:

```
def job(threadname, q):
  from queue import Empty
  from time import sleep
  c = 0
  while True:
    sleep(0.1) #slow the loop down 
    c += 1
    print(c)
    #Below is the changed part
    ch = None
    try:
      ch = q.get(block=False)
    except Empty:
      pass
    if ch is not None:
      handle_keypress(ch)
```